# Display MySQL results from database that lists values rather than organized columns

Tags: mysql, wordpress, select, gravity-forms-plugin

On WordPress we use Gravity Forms to collect user data.  I'm having a time displaying results efficiently or correctly so I can manipulate it and create a client listing page.

I'm accustomed to seeing a database like so:

### id | firstname | lastname | etc. | form_id

1  |  John     |  Doe     |  x   |  12

but Gravity forms stores the data like this:

### id | field_number | form_id | value

1  |   8          |   3     |  John

2  |   14         |   3     |  Doe

Of course there are several field_numbers that correspond with first name, last name, address, phone, etc. but I didn't list them.

So all i want to do is run a SELECT statement and display results nice and organized like:

John Doe  (which needs 2 fields lined up next to each other in the loop)

Address   (of course I can put a 
 in the loop to break)
etc.

I apologize but I haven't pulled data this way and I don't even know what it's called.

My code below is a feeble attempt to display things but I know it has to be completely inefficient and incorrect.  What is the correct way to pull data and what is this type of storage called (the way Gravity Forms is doing it)?

```
global $wpdb;
$rows = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT form_id, value, field_number FROM     
wp_rg_lead_detail WHERE form_id=3" );
foreach( $rows as $row ) {
if($row->field_number==1) {
    echo $row->value; 
}
if($row->field_number==8) {
    echo $row->value; 
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I don't have a clean solution for you, and I don't know what this form of storage is called, other than truly evil.  That said, I figured given that it's been a few hours with no responses, you might appreciate a few new ideas as possible paths to experiment with.  I'm including 2 trains of thought here which should work with mods for the rest of your data, although still icky. Good luck.

```
select distinct
  f.form_id, 
  concat(first.val, ' ', last.val) as name
from
  form f
  inner join 
   (select f1.form_id, f1.val from form f1 where f1.field_number = 8) as first
   on f.form_id = first.form_id
  inner join 
   (select f2.form_id, f2.val from form f2 where f2.field_number = 14) as last
   on f.form_id = last.form_id
  where f.form_id = 3;


select distinct
  f.form_id, 
  n.name
from
  form f
  inner join 
    (select 
       form_id, 
       group_concat(distinct val order by field_number asc separator ' ') as name
     from 
       form 
     where 
       field_number = 8 
       or field_number = 14 
     group by form_id) n 
   on f.form_id = n.form_id
  where f.form_id = 3;
```